Audited entity can't be deleted due to missing created_by, which otherwise works
I am using spring boot 3 with envers and auditing.
Auditing works fine for creating and editing an entity, but for deleting an entity I get the following error:
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: 
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement 
[ERROR: null value in column "created_by" of relation "price_item_aud" violates not-null constraint
Detail: Failing row contains (356, 2, 8ca32c7d-d087-49b9-be0a-1158bb105ff9, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).] [insert into public.price_item_aud (revend,revend_tstmp,revtype,created_by,created_date,modified_by,modified_date,...,rev,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,...,?,?)]; SQL [insert into public.price_item_aud (revend,revend_tstmp,revtype,created_by,created_date,modified_by,modified_date,...,rev,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; constraint [created_by" of relation "price_item_aud]] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "created_by" of relation "price_item_aud" violates not-null constraint

When creating or editing the same entity the created_by and all the other fields are populated correctly but not on delete. Also, the AuditorAware is not called on delete.
Am using the following special configuration:
        audit_strategy: "org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy"
        audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp: true

I tried to use multiple delete methods, but none seem to trigger the JPA Auditing.
Delete also worked fine before adding JPA Auditing, so I assume it is not due to the evers setup. And since the JPA Auditing works on create and modify and created_by is filled out in the entity table and the _aud table correctly I would ask for any further ideas where to look.

I found here that adding
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      org:
        hibernate:
          envers:
            store_data_at_delete: true

solves the issue.
Alternatively, I could have removed the NotNull constraint for the JPA Auditing fields, but I think this solution is better in my case as deletion is not a frequent action.
